# How to ListView opens a new activity using onClick?

Tags: android, string, listview, apk

Hi, Everybody.My goal is when I want to click on a specific item from the ListView, it opens a new activity that I've programmed. For example: when I click on "João", I wish it opens a class called Joao. I've tried using a simple code, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens when I click on João's name from ListView.

This is my code that I'm using:

```
public class Searchsort extends Activity {

    private ListView lv1;
    private EditText ed;
    private String lv_arr[]={"John","Mary","Carl","Rose","Charlie","Allan", "João"};
    private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
    int textlength=0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

        // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.

        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,   lv_arr));
        ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                textlength=ed.getText().length();
                arr_sort.clear();
                for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++) {
                    if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length()) {
                        if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,  textlength))) {
                            arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>  (Searchsort.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr_sort));

            }
        });
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        if ("João".equals(lv_arr[position])) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, Joao.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the problem in using a switch or if condition??

Answer (score 0):

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       Intent intent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, Joao.class);                                                  

                    startActivity(intent);          
                }
            }        
        });
```

Comment: I think I explained to you wrongly. To clarify and improve my question. Each element (name) of string should open a new activity that I want. For example "Mary" should open "x.class". John opens "y.class", Charlie shoud opens "y.class", João "joao.class", so on...Got it?

Comment: What is the problem in using my code? public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        if ("João".equals(lv_arr[position])) { 
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Searchsort.this, Joao.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` for the `ListView` and handle activity opening there.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `Androidmanifest.xml`.

Add declare like:

```
<activity android:name=".CLASS_NAME"> </activity>
```

You must declare all activitIes like that.

Comment: Yeah. I know. I declared my activities. But it still doesn't work! What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

As Niko Suggested use setOnItemClickListener() in the following manner.

```
public class Searchsort extends Activity {

private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
private String lv_arr[]={"John","Mary","Carl","Rose","Charlie","Allan", "João"};
private ArrayList<String> arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;
private String getItem;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lv1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

    // By using setAdpater method in listview we an add string array in list.

    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
    // Here I have set Listener for listview 
    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 // Here I am getting the selected item of listview.
            getItem = (arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());

            if(getItem.equals("John"))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Searchsort.this,John.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
    ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            textlength=ed.getText().length();
            arr_sort.clear();
            for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++) {
                if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length()) {
                    if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0,  textlength))) {
                        arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>  (Searchsort.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arr_sort));
        }
    });
}    
 }
```

Comment: Hi. I've tried this. But doesn't work. I mentioned my activity in manifest file. Could you clarify this putting this code in my code, please? As a I said before: nothing happesn when I click on someone's name from ListView :/

Comment: @user1550421 I have made the required changes in the post please find it and let me know is it working or not. :)

Comment: @user1550421 Have you tried the updated code.Is it working or not?

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

if(position == 1)
{

         Intent myIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}

if(position == 2)
{

         Intent myIntent =  new Intent(YourActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
             startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
}
    }
  });
```

Hope this will help you :-)